# Python: pip install pip install --platform manylinux_2_28_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:

Tags: python, pip

I'm using this pip command to install a binary version of cryptography.

`python3.9 -m pip install --platform manylinux_2_28_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: cryptography  -t build`

However, I'm getting the following error. How should I fix it without version locking?

```
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-40.0.2-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.7 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-40.0.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.7 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-40.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.7 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.2-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-38.0.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-38.0.3-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-38.0.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
  Using cached cryptography-38.0.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.2 MB)
ERROR: Cannot install cryptography==38.0.0, cryptography==38.0.1, cryptography==38.0.3, cryptography==38.0.4, cryptography==39.0.0, cryptography==39.0.1, cryptography==39.0.2, cryptography==40.0.0, cryptography==40.0.1 and cryptography==40.0.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    cryptography 40.0.2 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 40.0.1 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 40.0.0 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 39.0.2 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 39.0.1 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 39.0.0 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 38.0.4 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 38.0.3 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 38.0.1 depends on cffi>=1.12
    cryptography 38.0.0 depends on cffi>=1.12
```

Comment: Seems like you should upgrade your cffi or whatever else depends on an old version of it. (Also, version locking is a *good* thing.)